# What will happen when a collision in SHA256 be found?

Tags: hash, consensus, sha256, governance

Would the protocol migrate to another Hash Algorithm inmediatly?
What would be the next? SHA3 or BLAKE 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hash function has ever been broken in a way that would be meaningfully have an impact to Bitcoin. It’s not even a consideration, other than  for `OP_SHA1` which has no non-academic usage in Bitcoin.

Comment: Some cryptographers thinks that is matter of time to find a collision a in SHA256. I know won't be soon, but what will happen when that collision be found? a Hard Fork?

Comment: Nowhere in Bitcoin would a SHA256 collision actually matter.